# Use metres instead of px in Leaflet styles

Tags: leaflet

As far as I can tell, Leaflet styling units are always pixels. I need to style things in geographic units (technically "mapunits" derived from the projection, but just metres would be a good start).

How can I write style rules to express eg the width of a line feature in metres, not pixels?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545098/leaflet-calculating-meters-per-pixel-at-zoom-level

Comment: Ah, yes, that might get me there - the reciprocal should take me from metres to pixels, I guess?